# Implementing Kurento Client with WebRTC on Android

Tags: java, android, webrtc, kurento

I'm trying to implement WebRTC on an android device supporting API 22 and I'm trying to connect to Kurento Media Server to establish media server capabilities. For my application Server layer, I'm trying to utilize a Java Server based on Tomcat, and this is implementing a Kurento Client API to connect to the Kurento Media Server. The issue I am having is understanding how to go about establishing a connection between the Android device and Kurento and doing a media transfer after the connection has been authorized by the Application Server and a SDP response has been processed by the Kurento Client initialized on the Application/Signaling Server. I came across Kurento Android SDK (Kands) but the repositories are missing sources on Maven and Gradle. Any help here in implementing the WebRtc.org stack with Kurento would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KANDS will not help you much for several reasons. First, it is an outdated and unmaintained project. Second, with the setup you describe, I think you'd be barking at the wrong tree. In your case, the signalling that should be implemented in your Android client, should be between the client and your app server. As you can see in the following image, which depicts your proposed setup, your client will be connecting to an app server using your own signalling protocol, and it is you app server the one in charge of controlling KSM.

[image: Described architecture with app server controlling KMS]

In this way, you can implement all your business logic in the app-server, and you'll be able to make upgrades in the media part, shielding your clients by hiding the underlying implementation. The only thing that you'll need, is to get the SDP offer from your client to the KMS (going through your app server), have the KMS process that offer, and send the answer back to your client.

With this setup, you'll also have the posibillity to connect Android clients to any other type of webrtc capable clients, such as browsers.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've been following your answers and I was hoping you'd respond considering you're on the Kurento team. 

So here's the dilemma I'm facing. How to write the Kurento Client for Native Android applications? I thought that was what KANDS was for...or am I wrong there? And if KANDS is not being maintained, I'm assuming that the only way to go about creating a Kurento Client on Android is in a hybrid app? Without KANDS, how to generate the SDP offer and then have the media flow b/w KMS and Android? Please let me know if this approach that I'm thinking on is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @dranz3r that was only a part of what KANDS was doing, and a small one by the way. I think you can use that project as a base on to how to get the webrtc connection working.

Comment: Ohk thanks! Just one other question...if I add an SSL certificate to the KMS config log and specify the connection to be HTTPS from the Kurento Utils JS Client (I switched to using webviews instead of KANDS), it should go through as SSL secured connection, right? Or do  need to make any additional config changes for that connection to be secure? Thanks!

Comment: Kurento-utils-js does not directly connect to KMS, that depends on what you use to communicate with KMS. Kurento-client does, but please post this in a new question so we don't mix information, and up-vote the answer if it has helped you :-)

Comment: I meant accept the answer, no up-vote. But you can do both if you feel like it.

Comment: Ohk. I will. And I tried to accept the answer and upvote it. I think it failed because of no "reputation" on here. I'll try again once I get to my laptop. Also, I wasn't sure you'd get to the answer so I was an ass by posting it here (I know). I'll do that and post a link here. Thanks much!

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374609/how-to-implement-kurento-client-js-with-your-own-tomcat-signalling-server-on-a) I posted the new question. I could use your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

KANDS was discontinued and SDk for android is only used for them to develop customized apps. Then we switched to webview also.