# How to implement Kurento Client JS with your own "Tomcat signalling server" on Android using a secure SSL connection to KMS?

Tags: android, ssl, webrtc, stun, kurento

So this is a two part question:

Part a: I'm trying to implement a secure connection to the KMS. From the documentation, I've understood that KMS Configuration file would need to be updated with the SSL certificate and then the HTTPS connection from the client can be made. Please let me know if there are any other steps that are involved in achieving SSL security.

Part b: From a better understanding now and from comments from a previous question I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972480/implementing-kurento-client-with-webrtc-on-android), Kurento Utils does not connect to KMS directly (this was an fyi and a clarification I received and I wanted documented here just in case). Now I'm trying to use Kurento Client to connect to KMS and I'm trying to understand the role of ICE/TURN/STUN servers acting as negotiators in the middle. If I were to specify my own server URL, I'm assuming that I would not need to include "freeice" and "normalice" and instead specify my own server's URL. In the code snippet below taken from the [tutorial](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/blob/release-5.1/kurento-recorder/index.js) on github, I'm assuming that I would need to replace the argument for ice_servers to point to the url where my server is running? Or since this is the client, do I really need an ICE server because as said from the first statement, the utils don't connect to the KMS but the client can, right? So if I were to specify the Kurento URL for "ws_uri" parameter, then I won't need to even use ICE servers...right? I don't really understand the concept of ICE/TURN servers very well in terms of how they integrate with Kurento and hence, I would like to understand in English as to what changes would I need to make in order to get this to work. I will bang my head to write the code myself! Thanks much in advance!

```
`
var args = getopts(location.search,
{
default:
{
ws_uri: 'ws://' + location.hostname + ':8888/kurento',
file_uri: 'file:///tmp/recorder_demo.webm', //file to be stored in media server
ice_servers: undefined
}
});`
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer A

Only this and nothing more... at least for KMS. On the client side, you'll need to specify the WSS port and so on.

## Answer B

Your client might need a STUN/TURN server, and that's independent of where KMS is located. STUN and TURN are used in the candidate harvest process, to discover the network topology of your peer. You have two peers: KMS and your Android app, and both need to have, in their SDPs and during the negotiation, a candidate that is reachable by them (app will connect with KMS and viceversa) If both peers are on the same network, you can go without using STUN/TURN. The moment you have a NAT in between, you need at least STUN for that peer to be able to harvest candidates that have the public IP on the other side of the NAT, which is not known by the peer unless STUN is used.

TURN is used as a relay server, and it is needed in a small set of cases. If you are almost certain you are going to use TURN, you need to have that in a machine different than KMS (it makes close to no sense to have both the relay server and the media server installed together)

So the answer is yes, you are most likely going to need STUN/TURN in your clients.